# How to sort a RDD?

Tags: scala, sorting, apache-spark

I'm a beginner in Spark and Scala. This is the RDD I finally have after 3 days :

```
((null,18),1)

((null,17),1)

((null,16),1)

((AK,14),2)

((Lo,6),1)

((Re,7),1)

((4x,10),1)

((null,12),4)

((Re,13),1)

((Mu,19),1)

((Lo,19),2)

((null,8),1)

((null,20),3)
```

I'm supposed to sort this RDD so that all values of a kind are grouped together in ascending order. Eg:

```
((null,8),1)

((null,12),4)

((null,16),1)

((null,17),1)

((null,18),1)

((null,20),3)

((Lo,6),1)

((Lo,19),2)
```

I have no idea where to look or how to begin.

Comment: Since you have nulls in your Tuple2 key, trying to sort will give you nullpointerexception.

Answer (score 1):

The `RDD` can be sorted using the `sortBy` method, e.g.:

```
val rdd: RDD[((String, Int), Int)] = ??? // your RDD
rdd.sortBy(_._1) // sort by the first item in the pair
```

Given that you are working with pairs, you can also use the `sortByKey` method:

```
rdd.sortByKey()
```